# php ввод/вывод json

Tags: php, json

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Отправляю на сервер строку `json` через `$post`.
В `firbug` видно, что вводимые данные отсылаются нормально.
И на получившейся странице

```
document.location = '/' + lang + '/h?5555=' + est;
```

пытаюсь вывести данные через `json_decode` на `php`.

Как не пытался, данные не приходят. Правильный ли следующий алгоритм действий:

*отправка Json -> Сервер -> вывод данных на получившийся странице*

Или может какой-то обработчик между всем этим нужен?

Comment: Пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы, более развернутые, показывайте больше примеров и то, что вы, уже сделали.

Answer (score 0):

$answer=json_encode($question);
echo $answer;

Comment: Пожалуйста давайте более развернутые ответы

Answer (score -1):

так как вы написали, выдает "null";

{"1":null,"2":null,"3":null};