# json вывод на страницу через php

Tags: php, json, вывод, ввод

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Отправляю на сервер строку json через $post. В firbug видно, что вводимые данные отсылаются нормально. И на получившейся странице

document.location = '/' + lang + '/h?5555=' + est;

пытаюсь вывести данные через json_decode на php.
Как не пытался, данные не приходят. Правильный ли следующий алгоритм действий:
отправка Json -> Сервер -> вывод данных на получившийся странице
Или может какой-то обработчик между всем этим нужен?

Comment: ну вы код то приведите свой, как отправляете, как выводите. а то написали какой то js, ни пришей кобыле хвост.

Comment: Фрагмент кода не поленитесь вставить

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684572/236011 дубль?